# Angular 4 Unit testing: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I just started to write unit test for my angular service and I am running in to a promise error.

Basically I have two services 
1.  Configuration service
2.  CountryDetails service 
The country details service uses the configuration service to return a observable.
Below is the code for the services

**Configuration service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
private config: any;
constructor(private http: Http) {
}
public loadConfig(): Promise<any> {
     return this.http.get('assets/env-config.json')
       .map(res => res.json())
       .toPromise()
       .then(settings => this.config = settings);
}
public get configuration(): any {
     return this.config;
   }
}
```

**CountryDetails Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Country } from '../models/country';
import {ConfigurationService  } from '../../services/configuration.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class CountryDetailsService {
public countryData: Country;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private configSvc: ConfigurationService
  ) { }
getData(isoCode: string): Observable<Country> {
  const endpointUrl = `${this.configSvc.configuration.CountryAPIUrl}Details/${isoCode}`;
  const country$ = this.http.get<Country>(endpointUrl);
  country$.subscribe(rslt => this.countryData = rslt);
  return country$;
}
}
```

**Test for CountryDetails**

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CountryDetailsService } from './countrydetails.service';
import {ConfigurationService  } from '../../services/configuration.service';
import { Country } from '../models/country';

import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

fdescribe('CountryDetailsService', () => {

  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  let countrySvc: CountryDetailsService;
  let configSvc:  ConfigurationService;

  let  http = TestBed.get(Http);

  let  expectedcountryData: Country ;
  const inputIsoCode = 'IN';

  beforeEach( async (() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [CountryDetailsService, ConfigurationService  ]
    });

    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);

    countrySvc = TestBed.get(CountryDetailsService);
    configSvc = new ConfigurationService(http);
    configSvc.loadConfig();

    countrySvc = TestBed.get(CountryDetailsService);
      expectedcountryData = {
        CountryId: 13415,
        IsoCode2: 'IN',
        IsoCode3: 'IND',
        LongName: 'India, Republic of',
        Name: 'India',
        Capital: 'New Delhi',
        NationalDay: '26 January',
        NumberOfAccession: 18,
        Ambassador: null,
        CurrentBoardMember: 'Y',
        MembershipStartDate: '1957-07-16T00:00:00'
      };
    }));


  afterEach(async(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  }));

  it('should return expected country (called once)', async( () => {
    countrySvc.getData(inputIsoCode).subscribe(
     countryData => {
       expect(countryData).toEqual(expectedcountryData, 'should return expected country i.e IN');
     }
 );

const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${this.configSvc.configuration.CountryAPIUrl}Details/${inputIsoCode}`);
 expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');

req.flush(expectedcountryData);
}));

});
```

**Error**

```
Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.
Error: Cannot call Promise.then from within a sync test.
    at SyncTestZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/sync-test.js.SyncTestZoneSpec.onScheduleTask ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js:30:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:1)
    at scheduleResolveOrReject ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:871:1)
    at ZoneAwarePromise.then ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:981:1)
    at ApplicationInitStatus.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js.ApplicationInitStatus.runInitializers ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:3457:1)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed._initIfNeeded ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:964:1)
    at TestBed.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed.get ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:1000:1)
    at Function.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/testing.js.TestBed.get ( ://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/VSO/CountryProfiles AngularApp/Iaea.CountryProfiles.Web/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/testing.js:805:1)

I would be grateful if someone can point out the exact problem in this
```